# Extra output outputted

Tags: javascript, html

In this code I want the output as a b c, but at the end there is another a outputting. So, how can I do it?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var story = document.getElementsByClassName('story')[0];

    let clone = story.cloneNode(true);

    let usr = ["a", "b", "c"];


    document.getElementsByClassName('story')[i].innerHTML = usr[i];


    document.getElementById("story").appendChild(clone);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="story">
  <p class="story"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: cloning an item does not delete the original item

Comment: Then, how can I get the required output? I tried deleting the the real element at the end of the code. But it creates another Bug. In this case  output is b c a .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer, I solved it myself.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    //changing index to i
    var story = document.getElementsByClassName('story')[i];

    let clone = story.cloneNode(true);

    let usr = ["a", "b", "c"];


    document.getElementsByClassName('story')[i].innerHTML = usr[i];


    document.getElementById("story").appendChild(clone);
  }
    //removing last child
    document.getElementsByClassName('story')[3].remove();
}
```

```html
<div id="story">
  <p class="story" style="background-color: red;"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is normal because you have three clones and original, so as final step you should remove original

```js
window.onload= function(){
    var main_story=document.getElementById("story");
    var story = document.getElementsByClassName('story')[0];
    let usr = ["a", "b", "c"];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {   
      let clone = story.cloneNode(true);          
      clone.innerHTML = usr[i];
      main_story.appendChild(clone);
    }
    story.remove();
}
```

```html
<div id="story">
    <p class="story"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: It outputs b c a but I want a b c

Comment: You may look before edited answer. Refresh page and look please @Kashyap Kumar

Answer (score 1):

```js
const setup = () => {
 let storySource = document.querySelectorAll('.story')[0];
  let story = document.querySelector('#story');
  let userList = ["a", "b", "c"];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  let clone = storySource.cloneNode(true);
    clone.textContent = userList[i];
    story.appendChild(clone);
  }
  storySource.remove();

};

//load
window.addEventListener('load', setup);
```

```html
<div id="story">
  <p class="story"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah just modernized his code and included the line he forgot. The code can still be improved. The variable names could be better, and depending on the context the loop could be changed. I didn't change the loop because there was not enough context for it to change.

Comment: That again depends on the context. Consider a class that could refer to more than one element. You aren't exactly sure what will happen with the code in the future and code that indicates the behaviour would be easier to modify & detect when someone doesn't work after a change then code that secretly targets the first element it finds without been descriptive about it.Just crossed my mind in case it ever needs debugging.

Comment: I don't think you understand the point that I try to point out. As a programmer, it's important that your code is descriptive as possible for yourself & fellow programmers. Using ``document.querySelectorAll('.story')[0]`` follows this matter by explaining you have no control over what your HTML will look like & within the rules, it could be possible more than one element exists that fits the description. When you are using ``document.querySelector('.story')`` just give you the idea that the code is looking to that element but gives you no insight in more complex DOM's.

Comment: A similar argument could be made with ``userList.forEach(user => { let clone = storySource.cloneNode(true); clone.textContent = user; story.appendChild(clone); });`` vs using ``for(index)`` loop. Depending on the context you could prefer the one over the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below:

```
window.onload= function(){
    let usr = ["a", "b", "c"];

    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      var story = document.createElement('p');
      story.classList.add('story');
      story.innerText= usr[i];
      document.getElementById("story").appendChild(story);
    }
  }
```

Also Update this as

```
<div id="story">
</div>
```

Comment: I can't do this because I have a large code in place of p element, it would be a very difficult code, I know the way.

Comment: @KashyapKumar in this case why don't you prefer my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

*cloning an item does not delete the original item*

> Then, how can I get the required output? I tried deleting the the real element at the end of the code. But it creates another Bug. In this case output is b c a .

if your element is complex you can also use the DOM parser to create your new element

```js
const DomParser   = new DOMParser()
  ,   usrTab      = ['a', 'b', 'c']
  ,   storyDiv    = document.getElementById('story')
  ;
const newElement_X=(arg)=>
  {
  let elmX = `<p class="story">${arg}</p>`
  return DomParser.parseFromString( elmX, 'text/html').body.firstChild
  }
window.onload=()=>
  {
  for (let usrVal of usrTab)
    {
    storyDiv.appendChild( newElement_X(usrVal) )
    }
  }
```

```html
<div id="story"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have a "P" node inside the "DIV" node. Then, you create another three. All together you get four "P" nodes.

Use the following codes to solve your problem.

```
window.onload = function() {

        let usr = ["a", "b", "c"];    

          for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {


            let newP = document.createElement("p");
            newP.setAttribute("class", "story");
            newP.innerHTML = usr[i];

            document.getElementById("story").appendChild(newP);
          }
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code is creating 3 elements + 1 already exists. I have updated the code to use the index.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const users = ["a", "b", "c"];
  
  users.forEach(function(user) {
    const el = document.createElement("p");
    el.innerHTML = user;
    el.className = 'story';
    
    document.getElementById("story").appendChild(el);
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="story"></div>
```

Comment: This is not correct answer @Kashyap Kumar. Inspect element here also there are 4 elements but last one is empty. You just not see empty ones but there are here also 4 elements. Please check answer carefully

Comment: very bad code, at each loop time you create  "pointer" on '.story' first occurence + usr array + an other pointer on story Id element...

Comment: and there are still four  `<p class="story"></p>` left at the end, the last one is empty

Comment: it is completely different from your original code that the PO validated by becoming a copy of a solution already offered here

Comment: @pc_coder yup, this is not the right answer but i got a way to solve my problem. In my code when I removed the first child using remove() it created an error. but when I updated the index as in this answer then when I used remove() it worked.